# Menu Toggle on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle the .menu div on click. This is how far I've gotten and I'm puzzled as to why the javascript isn't working at all. Already tried out so much.

Help is much appreciated.

http://codepen.io/su1ts/pen/bZLwZN

**HTML:**

```
<header>    
    <button class="headerButton">
        <ul class="hamburger">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
    </ul>
  </button>
</header>

<div class="menu">a</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
header
    :width 100%
    :height 56px
    :color #FFF
    :position fixed
    :font-size 20px
    :z-index 9999
    button.headerButton
        :width 24px
        :height 24px
        :text-indent -30000px
        :overflow hidden
        :border none
        :outline none
        :cursor pointer
        :position absolute
        ul.hamburger
            :margin-top 4px
            :padding 0
            li
                :height 3px
                :width 12px
                :background blue
                :list-style none
                :margin auto
                :margin-bottom 2px
                :opacity 1
                :border-radius 1px
                :transition (.25s ease-in-out)

.menu
    :width 100%
    :height 100%
    :background-color rgba(10,10,10,0.95)
    :color white
    :position fixed
    :display none
    :z-index 14
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('button.headerButton').click(function() {
    $('.menu').toggle();
  });

});
```

Comment: you haven't added jquery to your codepen. There's a console error. Fix that then see what happens.

Comment: As @ADyson mentioned, you are missing jQuery reference in your codepen. Here is the working code - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyQgWQ

Comment: Thanks, I thought codepen adds those automatically. The pen is working now, unfortunately that doesn't do the trick on my original code where I already had added jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you forgot to add jQuery reference. Add this and It'll start working -

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My bad, I thought codepen adds that library automatically. It's working now, thanks a lot!

Comment: hang on, let me see

Comment: It's working now. I'm puzzled though, why it isn't working on my original code, since I already added jQuery there (I load it before my own script js and at the bottom before the closing body tag).

Comment: Try adding it before opening body tag, or in head tag

Comment: Also try replacing `(function() {

  $('button.headerButton').click(function() {
    $('.ss').toggle();
  });

});` with just `  $('button.headerButton').click(function() {
    $('.ss').toggle();
  });`

Comment: I found out the problem. It was that for some reason I had a type="javascript" declaration on my script.js tag, instead of nothing or type="text/javascript".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: OK great, Awesome!